# Mssql GROUP BY and "Image" field type

Tags: sql-server

i have problem with mssql query. This is a query:

```
    SELECT
     MAX(sprNomenklatura._IDRRef) AS 'link',
     pictures._Fld8035 AS 'picture'
    FROM
     _Reference62 sprnomenklatura
     LEFT JOIN _InfoRg8032 pictures
     ON pictures._Fld8033RRef = sprNomenklatura._IDRRef
   GROUP BY 
    sprnomenklatura._IDRref
```

The problem is that one of the fields i want to select (pictures._Fld8035) is "Image" type. This field can't be given to aggregate function like MAX, MIN e.t.c 
And i can't complete this query, cause mysql wants this field to be in some aggregate function or in "GROUP BY" statement (which not allowed by mssql too for data type "image").

What aggregate function should i use for this "image" field type to make query work?

Yes, it's able to split this query to 2 different, but sprNomenklatura._IDRRef field is binary data and putting its value into "IN" statement in second query results syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT link,pictures._Fld8035 as 'picture' 
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        MAX(sprNomenklatura._IDRRef) AS 'link'
        FROM _Reference62 sprnomenklatura
        GROUP BY sprnomenklatura._IDRref
    ) as a
    LEFT JOIN _InfoRg8032 pictures
        ON pictures._Fld8033RRef = a.link
```